# What is the correct way to dynamically create html based on the clicked path of an SVG and how do I go about hide/showing said html on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

**Issue**

I have an SVG which lets Users click on various body parts, the (SVGs path of the) body part when clicked gains the 'active' class which styles my css and sets some variables in my JS.

I'm trying to use these variables to dynamically create a html snippet (which includes input type elements) and then give that html element the 'active' class. From here the 'active' class should be applied to the html snippet and should be output to screen based on the variables set. The User should be able to click a different part and the corresponding snippet should be displayed and the old inactive snippet be hidden/removed.

I have the main SVG interaction done as far as I know, I have it so that clicking a body part displays the html based on the dynamic variables that are set.

After that I'm stumped, I had it so that it would add the active class but then only to the first item clicked and none of the others, I haven't managed to make the output display only the corresponding html snippets one at a time, each part clicked adds a new snippet to the screen. I'm also struggling to make the range slider value display in the dynamically created , something I have working for static (none dynamically created) elements (currently commented out and chucked at the bottom of the script).

I've also added a basic use case below the following code to help clarify what I'm looking to achieve.

[Here's what I have (SyncFiddle)](https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-MeQOi8i7y8k-sfxOMFP) so far or you can view the code below, though it's easier to see the full thing in SyncFiddle.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  // find everything in the svg with a data-part attribute
  const parts = document.querySelectorAll('svg [data-part]');

  // register a click listener on all the parts
  parts.forEach(p => p.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    // get the data-part value from the clicked element
    const {
      part
    } = e.target.dataset

    // do whatever you need to do with it
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = e.target.getAttribute('data-part');

    // Set the partId based on the click events 'id' attribute.  
    let partId = e.target.getAttribute('id');

    // toggle active class on clicked paths
    let targ = e.target.tagName == 'path' ? e.target : e.target.closest('path');
    $('svg').find('path').removeClass('active');
    $(targ).addClass('active')



    // Create html corresponding to clicked target using part and partId. 
    var html = [
      '<div id="mydiv" class="' + partId + '">',
'<label for="' + part + '">' + part + ' Score</label>', '<br>',
      '<span class="' + partId + 'Span "> 0 </span>',
      '<input type="range" class="custom-range" id="' + partId + '_scale" min="0" max="10" value="0"/>',
      '<br>',
      '<label for="' + part + '">' + part + ' notes</label>', '<br>',
      '<textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="additional' + partId + 'Info" rows="4"></textarea>',
      '</div>',
      '<hr>'
    ];



    // spawn html into the .body-input element
    $('.body-input').append(html);


  })); // end click event  
  
  
    // set span value to match the corresponding range slider val      
    // const $valSpan = $('.' + part + 'Span');
    // const $rangeVal = $('#' + part + '_scale');
    // $valSpan.html($rangeVal.val());
    // $rangeVal.on('input change', () => {
     // $valSpan.html($rangeVal.val());
    // });


} // end onLoad
```

```css
.human-body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 540px;
}

.human-body svg:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.human-body svg:hover path:nth-of-type() {
  fill: #530288;
}

path:hover {
  fill: #530288;
}

path.active {
  fill: #530288;
}

.human-body svg {
  fill: #0dead0;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  stroke: #530288;
  stroke-width: 0.264583px;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
}

#area {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Courier New;
  color: #a5a5a5;
}

#area #data {
  color: black;
}

.body-input>textarea {
  width: 90%;
  disply: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.body-input>input {
  width: 90%;
  disply: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="area">
  Area: <br><span id="data"></span>
  <div class="body-input"></div>
</div>


<div class="human-body">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 320 320">
    <g class="body-front">
      <path
        id="head"
         data-part="Head [ Front ]"
         d="m 104.3253,8.3065067 c 8.26218,-0.100026 12.48099,
            6.9018363 12.30482,15.3040713 
            l 1.89306,0.200053 -0.54089,5.30141 -3.31285,1.20032 -1.01412,6.601756
            -5.74674,6.201649 h -6.35522 l -5.814357,-6.501729 -1.216977,
            -6.301676 -2.974801,-0.800213 -0.878887, -6.101623 1.825441,
            -0.200053 C 92.73655,15.076304 97.283635,
            8.4065337 104.3253,8.3065067 Z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-chest"
        data-part="Left Chest"
         d="m 108.37671,53.361363 9.35444,-1.002263 c 9.45048,
            11.711603 7.53344,12.764242 
            7.02335,23.10735 l -8.26046,2.939965 -10.79003,-5.668014 z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-ribs"
         data-part="left-ribs"
         d="m 125.37066,78.278872 -8.78275,2.985031 -11.00856,
            -4.77195 0.70871,16.914434 
            8.78795,2.59859 6.66183,-3.35454 0.99219,-6.614585 z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-oblique"
         data-part="Left Oblique"
         d="m 122.11465,96.364698 -6.62294,3.23106 -0.24765,
            8.835192 6.95678,-4.11049 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-chest"
         data-part="Right Chest"
         d="M 100.8815,53.361363 91.527064,52.3591 C 82.07659,
            64.070703 83.993626,65.123342 
            84.50372,75.46645 l 8.260454,2.939965 10.790016,-5.668014 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-ribs"
         data-part="Right Ribs"
         d="m 83.954321,78.278872 8.782743,2.985031 11.008556,
            -4.77195 -0.70871,16.914434 
            -8.78794,2.59859 -6.66183,-3.35454 -0.992187,-6.614585 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-oblique"
         data-part="Right Oblique"
         d="m 87.484293,96.364698 6.622937,3.23106 0.04725,
            8.835192 -6.756326,-4.11049 z"
         />
      <path
        id="stomach"
         data-part="Stomach"
         d="m 104.83475,96.727018 9.18739,2.93997 -0.3675,
            9.655112 -8.64711,4.24766 
            -9.326759,-4.31447 -0.200451,-9.755342 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-shoulder"
         data-part="Right Shoulder [ Front ]"
         d="m 95.561129,38.121626 -0.46772,2.338609 -14.777371,
            6.280833 -7.483547,7.951269 
            3.87541,3.274051 6.614914,1.603619 4.677217,
            -8.68626 6.492017,-3.474503 
            8.352151,6.013564 -2.20496,-8.418992 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-upper-arm"
         data-part="Right Upper Arm [ Front ]"
         d="m 82.954089,61.106807 -6.629288,-1.74322 -4.112119,
            -3.537773 
            -2.619761,37.614113 5.437376,-6.537854 4.126128,8.870844 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-elbow"
         data-part="Right Elbow [ Front ]"
         d="m 74.83912,89.860944 -5.111529,5.746297 3.040191,
            9.488069 6.247425,-5.779709 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-lower-arm"
         data-part="Right Lower Arm [ Front ]"
         d="m 78.707562,101.78935 -6.575444,6.08677 -3.14793,
            -11.228582 -6.331117,15.591522 
            -2.348898,17.6786 3.610917,-0.82867 1.99665,
            3.75127 11.306845,-18.80582 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-wrist"
         data-part="Rigth Wrist [ Front ]"
         d="m 62.841794,130.89278 1.87089,3.842 -0.55125,
            2.47225 -4.092557,-0.25057 
            -1.95441,-3.69166 0.95215,-1.38646 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-hand"
         data-part="Right Hand [ Front ]"
         d="m 63.459257,139.0451 -4.276307,-0.26727 -2.37202,
            -4.44335 -7.550354,3.00678 
            -4.777437,4.34313 0.4009,1.46998 5.679477,
            -2.27179 0.935437,1.06907
            -6.414464,12.12736 2.204977,0.10023 4.309717,
            -6.74856 0.96885,0.90203
            -3.274047,7.6506 2.405427,0.30067 
            3.44109,-7.68399 1.837477,0.26726 -2.572467,
            7.38332 2.104747,0.30068
            2.67269,-7.3165 
            1.83748,-0.13364 -1.83748,6.9156 1.9043,
            0.20046 2.639277,-10.28988 z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-shoulder"
         data-part="Left Shoulder [ Front ]"
         d="m 114.0114,38.121626 0.46772,2.338609 14.77738,
            6.280833 7.48355,7.951269 -3.87541,
            3.274051 -6.61492,1.603619 -4.67722,
            -8.68626 -6.49202,-3.474503 -8.35217,
            6.013564 2.20497,-8.418992 z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-upper-arm"
         data-part="Left Upper Arm [ Front ]"
         d="m 126.97739,61.106807 6.62929,-1.74322 4.11213,
            -3.537773 2.61976,
            37.614113 -5.43738,-6.537857 -4.12613,8.870847 z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-elbow"
         data-part="Left Elbow [ Front ]"
         d="m 135.09236,89.860944 5.11154,5.746297 -3.04019,
            9.488069 -6.24744,-5.779709 z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-lower-arm"
         data-part="Left Lower Arm [ Front ]"
         d="m 131.29241,101.78935 6.57545,6.08677 3.14793,
            -11.228582 6.33112,15.591522 
            2.33744,17.75995 -3.61092,-0.82867 -1.99665,
            3.75127 -11.29539,-18.88717 z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-wrist"
         data-part="Left Wrist [ Front ]"
         d="m 147.15819,130.89278 -1.87089,
            3.842 0.55125,2.47225 4.09256,
            -0.25057 1.95441,-3.69166 
            -0.95215,-1.38646 z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-hand"
         data-part="Left Hand [ Front ]"
         d="m 146.54073,139.0451 4.27631,-0.26727 2.37202,
            -4.44335 7.55036,
            3.00678 4.77744,4.34313 -0.4009,
            1.46998 -5.67948,-2.27179 -0.93544,1.06907 6.41447,
            12.12736 -2.20498,
            0.10023 -4.30972,
            -6.74856 -0.96885,0.90203 3.27405,7.6506 -2.40543,
            0.30067 -3.44109,
            -7.68399 -1.83748,0.26726 2.57247,7.38332 -2.10475,
            0.30068 -2.67269,
            -7.3165 -1.83748,-0.13364 1.83748,6.9156 -1.9043,
            0.20046 -2.63928,-10.28988 z"
         />
    
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Basic Use Case**

User clicks the left arm, the dynamically created html snippet is then displayed showing the user the inputs for the left arm, the User uses the slider to set a value and inputs some basic notes regarding that body part. The User then clicks the head this hides the element created for the left arm and shows the inputs for the head where they input their data etc. The values from each body part the User clicks and provides input to will be saved in a database once the user has clicked a submit button.

**-----**

Don't worry about the databasing part as that's only in the Use Case to provide a full example of use.

I hope I've provided enough info for someone to be able to talk me through my issue, if not I'll be happy to provide more.
Thanks in advance,
Twist

Answer (score 0):

Check the following snippet out, I've marked my edits with comments.

```js
const parts = document.querySelectorAll('svg [data-part]');

const DB = {}; // DATABASE Object that holds values

parts.forEach(p => p.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  const {
    part
  } = e.target.dataset

  document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = e.target.getAttribute('data-part');

  let partId = e.target.getAttribute('id');

  let targ = e.target.tagName == 'path' ? e.target : e.target.closest('path');
  $('svg').find('path').removeClass('active');
  $(targ).addClass('active')

  // Some edits to set the correct values to input and textarea from the DB storage
  var html = [
    '<div id="mydiv" class="' + partId + '">',
    '<span class="' + partId + 'Span "> 0 </span>',
    '<input type="range" class="custom-range" min="0" max="10" value="' + (DB[partId] ? DB[partId].value : 0) + '"/>',
    '<br>',
    '<label for="' + part + '">' + part + ' notes</label>', '<br>',
    '<textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="additional' + partId + 'Info" rows="4">' + (DB[partId] ? DB[partId].text :
      '') + '</textarea>',
    '</div>',
    '<hr>'
  ];

  // logic to store previous values
  const previousID = $("#mydiv").attr("class");
  if (previousID)
    DB[previousID] = {
      value: $("input").val(),
      text: $("textarea").val()
    }

  $(".body-input").children().remove();
  $('.body-input').append(html);


}));
```

```css
.human-body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 540px;
}

.human-body svg:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.human-body svg:hover path:nth-of-type() {
  fill: #530288;
}

path:hover {
  fill: #530288;
}

path.active {
  fill: #530288;
}

.human-body svg {
  fill: #0dead0;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  stroke: #530288;
  stroke-width: 0.264583px;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
}

#area {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Courier New;
  color: #a5a5a5;
}

#area #data {
  color: black;
}

.body-input>textarea {
  width: 90%;
  disply: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.body-input>input {
  width: 90%;
  disply: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="area">
  Area: <br><span id="data"></span>
  <div class="body-input"></div>
</div>


<div class="human-body">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 320 320">
    <g class="body-front">
      <path
        id="head"
         data-part="Head [ Front ]"
         d="m 104.3253,8.3065067 c 8.26218,-0.100026 12.48099,
            6.9018363 12.30482,15.3040713 
            l 1.89306,0.200053 -0.54089,5.30141 -3.31285,1.20032 -1.01412,6.601756
            -5.74674,6.201649 h -6.35522 l -5.814357,-6.501729 -1.216977,
            -6.301676 -2.974801,-0.800213 -0.878887, -6.101623 1.825441,
            -0.200053 C 92.73655,15.076304 97.283635,
            8.4065337 104.3253,8.3065067 Z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-chest"
        data-part="Left Chest"
         d="m 108.37671,53.361363 9.35444,-1.002263 c 9.45048,
            11.711603 7.53344,12.764242 
            7.02335,23.10735 l -8.26046,2.939965 -10.79003,-5.668014 z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-ribs"
         data-part="left-ribs"
         d="m 125.37066,78.278872 -8.78275,2.985031 -11.00856,
            -4.77195 0.70871,16.914434 
            8.78795,2.59859 6.66183,-3.35454 0.99219,-6.614585 z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-oblique"
         data-part="Left Oblique"
         d="m 122.11465,96.364698 -6.62294,3.23106 -0.24765,
            8.835192 6.95678,-4.11049 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-chest"
         data-part="Right Chest"
         d="M 100.8815,53.361363 91.527064,52.3591 C 82.07659,
            64.070703 83.993626,65.123342 
            84.50372,75.46645 l 8.260454,2.939965 10.790016,-5.668014 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-ribs"
         data-part="Right Ribs"
         d="m 83.954321,78.278872 8.782743,2.985031 11.008556,
            -4.77195 -0.70871,16.914434 
            -8.78794,2.59859 -6.66183,-3.35454 -0.992187,-6.614585 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-oblique"
         data-part="Right Oblique"
         d="m 87.484293,96.364698 6.622937,3.23106 0.04725,
            8.835192 -6.756326,-4.11049 z"
         />
      <path
        id="stomach"
         data-part="Stomach"
         d="m 104.83475,96.727018 9.18739,2.93997 -0.3675,
            9.655112 -8.64711,4.24766 
            -9.326759,-4.31447 -0.200451,-9.755342 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-shoulder"
         data-part="Right Shoulder [ Front ]"
         d="m 95.561129,38.121626 -0.46772,2.338609 -14.777371,
            6.280833 -7.483547,7.951269 
            3.87541,3.274051 6.614914,1.603619 4.677217,
            -8.68626 6.492017,-3.474503 
            8.352151,6.013564 -2.20496,-8.418992 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-upper-arm"
         data-part="Right Upper Arm [ Front ]"
         d="m 82.954089,61.106807 -6.629288,-1.74322 -4.112119,
            -3.537773 
            -2.619761,37.614113 5.437376,-6.537854 4.126128,8.870844 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-elbow"
         data-part="Right Elbow [ Front ]"
         d="m 74.83912,89.860944 -5.111529,5.746297 3.040191,
            9.488069 6.247425,-5.779709 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-lower-arm"
         data-part="Right Lower Arm [ Front ]"
         d="m 78.707562,101.78935 -6.575444,6.08677 -3.14793,
            -11.228582 -6.331117,15.591522 
            -2.348898,17.6786 3.610917,-0.82867 1.99665,
            3.75127 11.306845,-18.80582 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-wrist"
         data-part="Rigth Wrist [ Front ]"
         d="m 62.841794,130.89278 1.87089,3.842 -0.55125,
            2.47225 -4.092557,-0.25057 
            -1.95441,-3.69166 0.95215,-1.38646 z"
         />
      <path
        id="right-hand"
         data-part="Right Hand [ Front ]"
         d="m 63.459257,139.0451 -4.276307,-0.26727 -2.37202,
            -4.44335 -7.550354,3.00678 
            -4.777437,4.34313 0.4009,1.46998 5.679477,
            -2.27179 0.935437,1.06907
            -6.414464,12.12736 2.204977,0.10023 4.309717,
            -6.74856 0.96885,0.90203
            -3.274047,7.6506 2.405427,0.30067 
            3.44109,-7.68399 1.837477,0.26726 -2.572467,
            7.38332 2.104747,0.30068
            2.67269,-7.3165 
            1.83748,-0.13364 -1.83748,6.9156 1.9043,
            0.20046 2.639277,-10.28988 z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-shoulder"
         data-part="Left Shoulder [ Front ]"
         d="m 114.0114,38.121626 0.46772,2.338609 14.77738,
            6.280833 7.48355,7.951269 -3.87541,
            3.274051 -6.61492,1.603619 -4.67722,
            -8.68626 -6.49202,-3.474503 -8.35217,
            6.013564 2.20497,-8.418992 z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-upper-arm"
         data-part="Left Upper Arm [ Front ]"
         d="m 126.97739,61.106807 6.62929,-1.74322 4.11213,
            -3.537773 2.61976,
            37.614113 -5.43738,-6.537857 -4.12613,8.870847 z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-elbow"
         data-part="Left Elbow [ Front ]"
         d="m 135.09236,89.860944 5.11154,5.746297 -3.04019,
            9.488069 -6.24744,-5.779709 z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-lower-arm"
         data-part="Left Lower Arm [ Front ]"
         d="m 131.29241,101.78935 6.57545,6.08677 3.14793,
            -11.228582 6.33112,15.591522 
            2.33744,17.75995 -3.61092,-0.82867 -1.99665,
            3.75127 -11.29539,-18.88717 z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-wrist"
         data-part="Left Wrist [ Front ]"
         d="m 147.15819,130.89278 -1.87089,
            3.842 0.55125,2.47225 4.09256,
            -0.25057 1.95441,-3.69166 
            -0.95215,-1.38646 z"
         />
      <path
        id="left-hand"
         data-part="Left Hand [ Front ]"
         d="m 146.54073,139.0451 4.27631,-0.26727 2.37202,
            -4.44335 7.55036,
            3.00678 4.77744,4.34313 -0.4009,
            1.46998 -5.67948,-2.27179 -0.93544,1.06907 6.41447,
            12.12736 -2.20498,
            0.10023 -4.30972,
            -6.74856 -0.96885,0.90203 3.27405,7.6506 -2.40543,
            0.30067 -3.44109,
            -7.68399 -1.83748,0.26726 2.57247,7.38332 -2.10475,
            0.30068 -2.67269,
            -7.3165 -1.83748,-0.13364 1.83748,6.9156 -1.9043,
            0.20046 -2.63928,-10.28988 z"
         />
    
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent and thank you, I had tried using a ternary similar to what I have for the targ variable but it just wouldn't work, is there any chance you could help with making the <span> value match the range slider?  I'm guessing it's something quite easy but JS has fried my brain this afternoon.

Comment: There is also an issue that occurs with this answer meaning when a user double clicks after selecting the first part, it sets the values as the previously set values and when clicking on differing parts the values are not being stored. My initial way of adding the data to my db was via a form and PHP, the idea being that each part clicked adds to the form and when the user clicks submit the form sends all the data from the clicked parts and default data for those not clicked. This form is also part of a larger form containing elements of a similar nature to the user inputs generated